# Extract the screenshot page where the text is found in azure cognitive search

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I have PDF documents stored in Azure Blobs that are indexed with Azure Search. I am searching for text in the content of the PDFs and everything works correctly. When I perform the search, is it possible that Azure returns a screenshot of the page where the text was found?

For example, if I search for the word 'information', which is on page 2 of a PDF, let Azure return a screenshot of that page.

thankssss

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of this in [the JFK sample](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/ai/ai-lab-jfk-files). The sample uses an [image store custom skill](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-power-skills/blob/main/Vision/ImageStore/README.md) that is used to extract the images and an [HOCR skill](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-power-skills/blob/main/Vision/HocrGenerator/README.md) to extract the data necessary to overlay zones corresponding to the text. The full skillset can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureSearch_JFK_Files/blob/master/JfkWebApiSkills/JfkInitializer/SearchResources.cs).
The front-end can then use that data to build [a HOCR viewer component](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureSearch_JFK_Files/tree/master/frontend/src/common/components/hocr) from that data.

I encourage you to read through the sample code to get the full details, that wouldn't fit in a Stack Overflow response.